# Going live with a project with no bugs generation

Tags: .net

What are the ways to ensure that minimum or no bugs are found when a .net project goes live? Your tips can be generic.

My first project is about to be hosted in a week's time and I am slightly intimidated by that fact, since I am a uni student and not an expert programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

> My first project is about to be hosted
>   in a week's time

---

Now that are lots of things to take care of during design and development (and it is quite late now). But one thing that I have found out that [continuous integration environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (wherein you also have testing and coverage checked) helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You will never know for sure that there are zero bugs in an application.

To reduce the risk of bugs, you could learn and implement [automated unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) with a framework like [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php).

As mentioned in one of Joel Spolsky's old articles, Microsoft had a "[zero defects methodology](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)" that focused on fixing bugs before writing new code.

Answer (score 0):

Code reviews, unit testing, automatic integrating testing and manual testing. I'm sure you heard about it at your uni.

Comment: I wish that was the case - I got a Computer Info Sys degree that taught me how to program, but I didn't learn anything about any of these topics. I wish practical programming was actually a common theme in university classes, but it's unfortunately much more rare than it ought to be.

Comment: apart from the obvious (manual testing) i have not heard about the other options you mentioned, hence the posed question.